# Sorting array elements using Arrays.sort

Tags: java, arrays, oop, sorting

For whatever reason, I cannot sort my array in the card array. I get an error that "Card cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable", even though I have a compareTo method for Card in my Card class. If I comment out the Arrays.sort(hand) method, the program runs as expected, but the results are off, as the hand needs to be sorted to see if the elements are equal to winning poker hands. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
//implements comparable<Card>
public class Card
{

//array for all of the possible faces
private static String[] faces = {"two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", 
    "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};

//array for all of the possible suits
private static String[] suits = {"clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"};

//variables used for the faces and suits
private String face;
private String suit;
private int faceValue;

//constructor for card; makes a Two of Clubs for testing purposes
public Card()
{
    face = "Two";
    suit = "Clubs";
}

//deal method; deals a random card
public void deal()
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    int thisCard = generator.nextInt(52);

    face = faces[thisCard % 13];
    suit = suits[thisCard / 13];

    faceValue = thisCard %13;
}

public int getFaceValue()
{
    return faceValue;
}

public String getFace() 
{
    return face;
}


public String getSuit() 
{
    return suit;
}

public String toString()
{
    return face  + " of " + suit + "  ";
}

public int compareTo(Card otherCard)
    {
    if (this.faceValue < otherCard.faceValue)
        return -1;
    else if (this.faceValue > otherCard.faceValue)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

}

public class Poker {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    //variables for winning hands
    int threeOfAKinds = 0;
    int fullHouse =0;
    int fourOfAKinds =0;
    int fiveOfAKinds = 0;
    int twoOfAKinds = 0;


    //create hand of cards
    Card [] hand = new Card [5];
    for (int i =0; i<5; i++)
        hand[i] = new Card();

    for (int x = 0; x<100; x++)
    {



    //deal cards 
    for (int i =0; i<5; i++)
        hand[i].deal();

    //print cards unsorted
    for (Card die : hand)
        System.out.print(die);
    System.out.println();

    //check for winning hands
    //sort to make this easier
    Arrays.sort(hand);




    //check for five of a kind
    if (hand[0].getFace()==hand[4].getFace())
        fiveOfAKinds++;
    //checks for full house
    else if (hand[0].getFace() == hand[1].getFace() && hand[2].getFace() == hand[4].getFace()||
            hand[0].getFace() == hand[2].getFace() && hand[3].getFace() == hand[4].getFace())
        fullHouse++;
    //check for four of a kind
    else if (hand[0].getFace() == hand[3].getFace() || hand[1].getFace() == hand[4].getFace())
        fourOfAKinds++;
    //check for 3 of a kind

    else if(        hand[0].getFace()==hand[2].getFace()
            || hand[1].getFace()==hand[3].getFace()
            || hand[2].getFace()==hand[4].getFace())
        threeOfAKinds ++;

    //check for two of a kind
    else if (hand[0].getFace()==hand[1].getFace()||
            hand[1].getFace()==hand[2].getFace() ||
            hand[2].getFace()==hand[3].getFace()||
            hand[3].getFace()==hand[4].getFace())
        twoOfAKinds++;

    //print cards sorted
            for (Card die : hand)
                System.out.print(die.getFace() + " " + die.getSuit());
            System.out.println();
    }       

    //report hands
    System.out.println("Five of a Kinds:" + fiveOfAKinds);
    System.out.println("4 of a kinds:" + fourOfAKinds);
    System.out.println("3 of a kinds:" + threeOfAKinds);
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having compareTo is not enough; you also need to implement the [`Comparable<Card>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, e.g.:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    ...
}
```

In addition it is preferable that your class also implements the `boolean equals(Object another)` method that would behave as if it returned `another instanceof Card && this.compareTo(another) == 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the error message `Card cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable` is important. It pretty much tells you your objects are not of type [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

If you look at the implementation of [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) you will notice a cast of your objects to the `Comparable` type. If your class does not implement `Comparable` interface, you will get that error.